# How to make chunked streaming PUT request to BaseHTTPRequestHandler not loose bytes?

Tags: python, linux, http, select

Consider the following MCVE, that runs a python program that:

- sets the global variable `FIXME` set during startup from the first command line argument
- in one thread starts a HTTP server

  - that listens to chunked PUT requests using `select` on the `self.rfile.fileno()`
  - and prints the received data
- in the main thread it runs a client for that HTTP server

  - if FIXME is true
    - sleep for 100 milliseconds
  - then sends a chunked PUT request with a single line of data using `requests` module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import select
import sys
import threading
import time
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, ThreadingHTTPServer
from typing import Iterator

import requests

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 10000
FIXME = True


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_PUT(self):
        inputfd = self.rfile.fileno()
        os.set_blocking(inputfd, False)
        while 1:
            print("SERVER SELECT")
            sel = select.select([inputfd], [], [inputfd])
            if inputfd in sel[2]:
                print(f"SERVER {inputfd} errored")
                break
            if inputfd not in sel[0]:
                print(f"SERVER read file descriptor closed")
                break
            chunk: bytes = os.read(inputfd, 8192)
            print(f"SERVER RECV {len(chunk)} {chunk!r}")
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                print(f"SERVER len(chunk) == 0")
                break
            if chunk:
                print(f"{chunk!r}")
            if b"0\r\n\r\n" in chunk:
                # terminating chunk
                break
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()


def server():
    with ThreadingHTTPServer((ip, int(port)), MyServer) as webServer:
        webServer.serve_forever()


class Client:
    def get_chunks_to_write(self) -> Iterator[bytes]:
        if FIXME:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print(f"CLIENT write")
        yield b"123"

    def main(self):
        requests.put(f"http://{ip}:{port}", data=self.get_chunks_to_write())


def cli():
    threading.Thread(target=server, daemon=True).start()
    # Wait for server startup
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Client().main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FIXME = int(sys.argv[1])
    cli()
```

When FIXME is set, the execution is fine:

```
$ ./test.py 1
SERVER SELECT
CLIENT write
SERVER RECV 13 b'3\r\n123\r\n0\r\n\r\n'
b'3\r\n123\r\n0\r\n\r\n'
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2023 11:14:01] "PUT / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However, when `FIXME` is false, then the execution blocks and the bytes are lost (takes about ~10 tries to reproduce with this MCVE, happens every time on real program):

```
$ ./1.py 0
CLIENT write
SERVER SELECT
```

What can I do to remove the extra sleep? What synchronization is missing? What is happening?

I *think* this happens, because the client closes or transfers bytes before the server can enter `select`. But I do not know how could that influence anything, as `select` should still allow processing the remaining bytes on the socket.

I tried searching the net. Setting `set_blocking(inputfd, True)` and `os.read(inputfd, 1)` also does *not* read the transferred bytes - I assume this is, as if, they were already read by `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. How can I access them?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select.select([inputfd]
> ```

You are right - python reads from the socket first and buffers the data. `select` selects on the underlying socket, however, python is buffering read data within `self.rfile`. Do not use `select.select` and `os.read()` on raw socket, instead use python wrappers with blocking read like `self.rfile.read()` and `self.rfile.readline()` which use the buffers managed by python.